# DAC converter: offset error

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, adc, dac, converter

If I have for example a 5-bit DAC converter with a Vref = 16V and the Vout = 0 when the input is '00000':
Can I calculate the offset error of this DAC if the Vout = 375mV and input is '00000000' even knowing that the DAC is of 5 bits?
Because if the input was '00000' instead of '00000000' I would do something like: 1LSB = 0.5V so the offset error = 0.375/0.5 = 0.75LSB

Comment: Do you mean 'even WITHOUT knowing'?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that a 5-bit DAC has an input of '00000000'? That makes no sense.